# What are "third-party modules"?

Tags: python, module, nomenclature

In researching the tool `distutils` I stumbled on the term *"third-party module"*. What does that mean?

Comment: *"Third-party"* means any module not written by you (first party) or included in the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/) (second party). *[Or maybe 1st and 2nd are the other way around, but the point stands!]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A third party module is any code that has been written by a third party (neither you nor the python writers (PSF)).

You can use them to add functionality to your code without having to write it yourself.

Examples include things like [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) that simplifies http requests and [`nose`](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) that helps with unit/integration testing.